# Best way to store and use config file in redis?

Tags: c#, redis, .net-core, stackexchange.redis, pcf

I have a config file with the following structure-

```
"Root":{
       "Parent":{
            "Child1":{"Key1":"Value1"},
                    {"Key2":"Value2"},
                    {"Key3":"Value3"}
            "Child2":{"Key1":"Value1"},
                    {"Key2":"Value2"},
                    {"Key3":"Value3"}
               }
       }
```

I want to store this config in Redis instance of my PCF. I am thinking of creating a database with ConnectionMultiplexer say "Config" then add each value with key as (Root:Parent:Child[i]:Key[i]) and value with corresponding value[i] for it. 
For reading the values I can ask for child[i] name and key[i] name from the consumer and return value[i].
Please suggest if anyone has a better way to achieve this? The config size could be very large up to 1000 child's.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you shouldn't use Redis to store your configuration, use [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-5/common/config-server/index.html) instead.

Config Server is purpose-built for storing application configuration, it has support for multiple environments and sharing common configuration across applications. Not only that, but you can use [Steeltoe's Config Server Configuration Provider](https://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-configuration/#2-0-config-server-provider) to access the configuration from within your application via `IConfiguration` without needing to write your own configuration provider for Redis or doing something else custom. It is also probably easier to maintain the config values with structured files in a git repository than a Redis dictionary, plus then all changes are easily audit-able and quick to revert via git history.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim for the suggestion. Currently, I am storing it in config server only but thinking to move it to Redis for fast retrieval and simultaneous access and modification by the various users. Wouldn't that be a good idea?

Comment: I don't know the full scope of your requirements, but I've laid out the general arguments for why config server should be a better choice for storing app configuration. App config is generally loaded into memory on startup, so I wouldn't expect the config server to be a bottleneck for you. Unless users _of your application_ need to be able to make changes to the config, I would think that git can handle your user-access concerns

Comment: another reason is I want to prevent the extra call to the config server each time the app restarts or some modification happens in the config that's why thinking of storing in Redis which will save these values in my app host container RAM